# Draw textfield on bitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I embed MovieClip that contains a lot of textfields. When I add those textfields to scene with addChild all works fine.

```
[Embed (source="/assets/movieclip.swf"]
private var libraryClass:Class;
...
var library:MovieClip = new libraryClass(); 
addChild(library.textfield);
```

But I need to draw textfields to bitmapData.

```
var _bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500, true, 0x000000);
var _bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(_bitmapData);
addChild(_bitmap);
...
var field:TextFiled = library.textfield;
_bitmapData.draw(field);
```

The problem is after I draw with bitmapData.draw method, I can't see any textfields. But if disable embedFonts it draw correctly:

```
var _field:TextFiled = library.textfield;
_field.embedFonts = false;
_bitmapData.draw(_field);
```

I need to draw with embed font...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting embedFonts to true causes the FP to use embeded font font for this text fields. Probably this font missing or it is not embeded correctly.

You need also to embed the font as well.